# Как добавить в один массив, те элементы из другого массива, которых еще нет в первом?

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, объекты

Есть массив объектов A. Из формы приходит другой массив объектов B. Как в массив A добавить объекты из массива B, которых в A еще нет?
Мой последний вариант:(метод класса, в котором есть массив объектов students)

```
addInGroup = studentsToAdd => {
let arr = [];
for (let studToAdd of studentsToAdd) {
  arr.push(this.students.filter(student => {
    return studToAdd.id !== student.id
  }))
}
this.students.push(...arr);
```

};

Comment: С вашим вариантом, у меня в студентах находятся пустые массивы, как и в моем варианте. Я полагаю, это от того, что arr пушится еще один массив, и получается массив массивов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я верно понял задачу, то

```
class YourClass {
  // ...
  addInGroup(studentsToAdd) {
    const ids = new Set(this.students.map(o => o.id)); 
    this.students = [
      ...this.students,
      ...studentsToAdd.filter(o => !ids.has(o.id))
    ];
  }
}
```

---

Вместо присвоения нового массива свойству `students`, можно использовать метод `splice` для добавления элементов "на месте":

```
this.students.splice(Infinity, 0,
  ...studentsToAdd.filter(o => !ids.has(o.id))
);
```

При указании `Infinity` первым аргументом (задающим начальный индекс вставки элементов), добавление будет выполнено в конец массива.

Comment: Круто, я очень долго бился над этой задачей)) А вот со splice я не понял...если я правильно понимаю, удали начиная с индекса infinity 0 элементов и вставь элементы из отфильтрованного массива. Но что за infinity индекс??

Comment: @Serafim, Когда первый аргумент содержит число больше длины массива, метод использует значение `length` в качестве индекса. Запись `Infinity` короче, чем `this.students.length` :)

Answer (score 0):

Производительней всего, а так же средствами языка **без посторонних классов** будет применить [контейнер Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) для полей *id* объектов *student*.

```
const ids = new Set([1,2,3])
console.log([...ids.values()]) // [1, 2, 3]
ids.add(4)
console.log([...ids.values()]) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
ids.add(1)
console.log([...ids.values()]) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```